# Error: Hash of java.xml (...) differs to expected hash (...) recorded in java.base

Tags: java, javafx, java-11, javafx-11, jlink

Creating simple javafx 11 "hello world" application.
Getting error while creating custom JRE.

```
user@user:~/Desktop/javafx/hellofx$ ./run.sh 
Error: Hash of java.xml (c043b4c28b897656e2a4d36c92ba2f5d52134bce79643236dd36295e14178be7) differs to expected hash (4e7db7fc941d9f316c4aafe02717b5809ee722be8433d283050365e7fd49331f) recorded in java.base
```

Error Code:

```
$JAVA_HOME/bin/jlink --module-path $PATH_TO_FX_MODS:mods --add-modules hellofx --output hellofx #error
```

OS: ubuntu 19.10

```
$java --version
openjdk 11.0.6 2020-01-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.6+10-post-Ubuntu-1ubuntu119.10.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.6+10-post-Ubuntu-1ubuntu119.10.1, mixed mode, sharing)
```

```
$javac --version
javac 11.0.6
```

```
user@user:~/Desktop/javafx/hellofx$ tree
.
├── mods
│   └── hellofx
│       ├── hellofx
│       │   └── HelloFX.class
│       └── module-info.class
├── run.sh
└── src
    ├── hellofx
    │   └── HelloFX.java
    └── module-info.java

5 directories, 5 files
```

run.sh:

```
user@user:~/Desktop/javafx/hellofx$ cat run.sh 
export PATH_TO_FX=/home/sameep/javafx-sdk-11.0.2/lib
export PATH_TO_FX_MODS=/home/sameep/javafx-jmods-11.0.2
javac --module-path $PATH_TO_FX -d mods/hellofx $(find src -name "*.java")

java --module-path $PATH_TO_FX:mods -m hellofx/hellofx.HelloFX

$JAVA_HOME/bin/jlink --module-path $PATH_TO_FX_MODS:mods --add-modules hellofx --output hellofx #error
#hellofx/bin/java -m hellofx/hellofx.HelloFX
```

module-info.java:

```
user@user:~/Desktop/javafx/hellofx/src$ cat module-info.java 
module hellofx {
    requires javafx.controls;

    exports hellofx;
}
```

HelloFX.java:

```
user@user:~/Desktop/javafx/hellofx/src/hellofx$ cat HelloFX.java 
package hellofx;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class HelloFX extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        String javaVersion = System.getProperty("java.version");
        String javafxVersion = System.getProperty("javafx.version");
        Label l = new Label("Hello, JavaFX " + javafxVersion + ", running on Java " + javaVersion + ".");
        Scene scene = new Scene(new StackPane(l), 640, 480);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

}
```

[image: Screenshot of output window]

Answer (score 3):

As you could follow in the links such as [this](https://github.com/moditect/moditect/issues/103), [this](https://github.com/beryx/badass-jlink-plugin/issues/111) and [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openjdk-lts/+bug/1851292/comments/5). It is more likely a JDK build issue and reverting to an older `java.version` e.g. 11.0.2 should fix this.

You can subscribe in the meanwhile to [openjdk-build/issues/1214](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-build/issues/1214) for further updates.

---

> When could this occur and what could cause this?

This could occur if the `jmod` files created for a module are not consistent in generating the hash. You can refer to the [JMOD tool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/jmod.htm#JSWOR-GUID-0A0BDFF6-BE34-461B-86EF-AAC9A555E2AE) documentation which elaborates on one of the arguments responsible for this

```
--hash-modules regex-pattern
```

> Determines the leaf modules and records the hashes of the dependencies
>   directly and indirectly requiring them, based on the module graph of
>   the modules matching the given regex-pattern. The *hashes are recorded
>   in the JMOD archive* file being created, or a *JMOD archive or modular
>   JAR on the module path* specified by the jmod hash command.

and furthermore in a subsided section describes

> ... This let’s you to allow a package to be exported to one or more
>   specifically-named modules and to no others through qualified exports.
>   ***The runtime verifies if the recorded hash of a module matches the one
>   resolved at run time; if not, the runtime returns an error***.